# Terms and condition update in AD B2C Custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My B2C policies are used by a mobile application and having long refresh token expiry date. My requirement is, how we can update the privacy policy and user should accept it to continue using the mobile app without him having to log out and login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fore users to check a box to accept the "terms of use" when the user signs up or sign in. But if the user already signed in, he **must login again** to trigger the check.

Here is an [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) regaring sign up and sign in with 'Terms of Use' prompt.